# NoMethodError: undefined method "add_import_path"

Tags: css, sass, compass

I recently upgraded my sass and compass version to the latest one. But its giving me an error while I start watcher.

Error is **`NoMethodError: undefined method add_import_path for main:Object`**

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after upgrading sass to 3.4.16 and compass to 1.0.3 `add_import_path` was giving error of undefined.

So I tried `additional_import_paths = []` which is working perfect now.